# Linux: X11 is using up 50% of one of my CPUs and lagging terribly

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, xorg, cpu-usage

I have been running my Ubuntu Linux Machine recently on powerful hardware (much more powerful
than my last machine at any rate) and I have noticed that after some time all of a sudden X11 starts
to behave terribly and eats a (fluxuating) average of 50% CPU usage of one of my cores. I have four
cores and my computer still runs but when that begins everything from keyboard input to playing
movies begins to lag and there is not way that I can get the terrible performance to stop without
rebooting my computer.

The exact specifications of my computer are:

> Linux ShhnapDesk 2.6.38-10-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 15:07:17 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64
>   x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am running XMonad and XMobar through my .XSession file. I like them as window managers.

I have searched around and I do not seem to be alone in this problem. Many people seem to have
encountered it over the years as is listed here:

- [ArchLinux Topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=102481)
- [GOS Forums](http://gosforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=702)
- [Launchpad Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/107950)
  This bug is particularily interesting because it shows that it is a well known problem but that
  people still could not find the cause.
- [Another launchpad bug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/30570)
- [Yet another launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/449196)
- [Debian Forums](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=57327)
- Many [Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=998615) [Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1404979) [Threads](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=938624)

I also looked into the [Ubuntu X Troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze) and found this:

> X CPU or memory load is high, making system laggy or freeze up. This usually indicates a client
>   application has lost its marbles.

So if an X application has lost its Marbles then which X application is it? Well I reasoned that if
the problem started and I shut down every X application then when I shut down the problem
application then the problem should go away. I tried that and shut down every X application (or
atleast I thought I did) and the problem still remained. Though I did not shut down XMonad because
it is my window manager. I guess that it could be the problem but I would not expect it to be.
Especially since it did not cause these issues on my last machine.

So my question is: what is happening and how do I fix it so that X11 stops going haywire and eating
all of my CPU and behaving like a slug? Thankyou for any and all responses, I suspect that I am
going to need alot of help though if I have missed out on any information then I can give you any
more that you need to help me debug the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem: about ones in an hour X11 is working hard for about a minute (Kubuntu 11.04).

Comment: Adobe: You make it sound like after an hour it goes back to normal. I would not consider that a huge problem, just an annoyance. With mine, once it starts lagging it never stops till I reboot the computer or completely restart X11 and gdm. Yuck.

Comment: Robert Massaioli: sounds like a serious problem. Seems to me to be a hardware one. Mine goes back to normal in a minute. But this is repeated in an hour.

Comment: Can you post: OS version, driver version, graphics card?